# Problem using :default => {:format => 'pdf'} in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, format, default

I want to route requests something like this: reports/bloodtypes is routed to controller reports, action bloodtypes, with format = pdf, and the route named as bloodtype_report. The Guides gives an example

```
match 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show', :defaults => { :format => 'jpg' }
```

When I do this:

```
match 'reports/bloodtypes' => 'reports#bloodtypes', :defaults => {:format => 'pdf'}, :as => 'bloodtype_report'
```

or this

```
match 'reports/bloodtypes' => 'reports#bloodtypes', :format => 'pdf', :as => 'bloodtype_report'
```

the controller *still* does not receive the `:format => 'pdf'` in `params`, and tries to render the report as HTML. The funny thing is that the route is shown by Rake as

```
 bloodtype_report :  /reports/bloodtypes(.:format) : {:format=>"pdf", :controller=>"reports", :action=>"bloodtypes"}
```

whether I use the first form (with :default) or second (just setting the format to pdf). It seems the route is correct, so why is the format parameter not being passed to the controller?

Comment: it works fine if I link directly to "reports/bloodtypes.pdf", or say `link_to "Blood types", :controller => :reports, :action=>:bloodtypes, :format=>'pdf'`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding this to your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf { render :pdf => "show" }
end
```

Comment: Actually, I have something in the format.pdf block and it works fine if I link directly to "reports/bloodtypes.pdf", or say `link_to "Blood types", :controller => :reports, :action=>:bloodtypes, :format=>'pdf'`

Comment: Ok... How are you trying to access the :format? like this: params[:format]?

Comment: Yes, params[:format], also just looking in the server log where it shows the parameters for a controller call. Is the format supposed to be accessed differently somehow?